# How to get order increment id using order id?

Tags: magento, increment

How can I get order increment id (like 100000028) with order id (like 28). In sales order page order increment id is like 100000028, but I have order id like 28.

How can I get order increment id by order id? I have tried below

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$result=$write->query("SELECT entity_id FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE `increment_id` = 'your increment id' ");
$row = $result->fetch();
echo $row['entity_id'];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
$Incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: This will get you the increment id from order id, but answer from @Colin is better, as this will not require you to load the order.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers require loading the entire order, which is overkill.  You can use this built-in method instead:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')->getIncrementId($orderId)
```

This will run a simple `SELECT` query to fetch just that one field.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in order to get Order increment id -

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order->load([Enter Order Id]);
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `preg_match`, which is easy and simple:

```
$o_id = preg_match('/10*(.*)/', $row[order_id], $o_id2 );
echo "Your order id is: $o_id2[1]"
```

As long as your increment id is like 10, it will work.